# Tornado 403 response raises error

Tags: python, tornado

In python, I am using the Tornado library's  HTTPRequest and AsyncHTTPClient().fetch method.  The response has a 403 status code.  Why does Tornado raise an error on a 403 response and how can I get more information from the error response?

For example, when I use the python "requests" library instead, I still get the 403 but I can inspect the body of the response and get more information, whereas Tornado raises an error and I can't access the response at all...

Comment: Unlike Flask, Tornado doesn't automatically log calls to the server.
You can, however, integrate logging so that you can see output.
You've got to integrate your logging in the view class.
Here's a good place on start on that.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/log.html

Answer (score 0):

RTFD

> This method returns a Future whose result is an HTTPResponse. By default, the Future will raise an HTTPError if the request returned a non-200 response code (other errors may also be raised if the server could not be contacted). Instead, if raise_error is set to False, the response will always be returned regardless of the response code.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html